# Proxy with Authentication in Selenium, JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, proxy

We try to use authenticated proxy in Selenium driving headless Chrome, JAVA.

`ChromeOptions` inherit from `ChromeCapabilities` (deprecated). We pass instance of [`Proxy` class](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Proxy.html) into a `ChromeOptions` instance.

The Selenium `Proxy` class has no methods of HTTP proxy to set up *username* & *password*:

```
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setAutodetect(false);
        proxy.setHttpProxy(proxyStr);
        proxy.setFtpProxy(proxyStr);
        proxy.setSslProxy(proxyStr);  
        chromeOptions.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
```

**Any way out?**

Comment: Maybe encode the username and password in the `proxyStr` string. E.g. `"http://username:password@my.proxy:port/"`?

Comment: @AZWN, if we apply *username* & *password* in the `proxyStr` in this way - failure, the same local IP.

Answer (score 0):

I think that good way is to use AutoIT tool.
It is described here: https://www.guru99.com/selenium-proxy-authentication.html#4